# What parameters are required to set Google Calender Notification time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api

I have to change the google calendar notification time from 30 minutes to 5 minutes.

```
const encodedUrl = encodeURI(
    [
      "https://www.google.com/calendar/render",
      "?action=TEMPLATE",
      `&text=${calendarEvent.title || ""}`,
      `&dates=${startDate || ""}`,
      `/${endDate || ""}`,
      `&add=elf1@example.com,elf2@example.com`,
      // TODO: append video appointment link to description
      `&details=${`${calendarEvent.description}\n` || ""}`,
      `&location=${calendarEvent.address || ""}`,
      "&sprop=&sprop=name:"
    ].join("")
  );
```

With the above URL string, I can set the event title, event timing, and event location parameters except for the notification time. But now I want to update the notification time in the calendar event in the above link, Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) resource from [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api) includes a `reminders` property, which can be used to manage event notifications.

Therefore, you can update the event notifications via [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch) or [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) by adding the `reminders` property to your payload.

For example, if you were calling this API on [Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), you would do something like this:

```
const resource = {
  reminders: {
    overrides: [
      {
        method: "popup", // options: "popup", "email"
        minutes: 5
      }
    ]
  }
}
Calendar.Events.patch(resource, calendarId, eventId);
```

If you need more information about how to use `Calendar API`, take a look at the different quickstarts available, for example [this one for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js).

#### Reference:

- [Reminders & Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/reminders)

Comment: Can you also look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374684/how-to-create-google-resource-calendar-using-any-api)?

Comment: And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755419/why-does-it-turn-into-an-unavailable-room-when-i-create-a-google-resource-calend) please