# How to create google resource calendar using any API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client, google-directory-api

I'm looking for a way to create resource calendars for shared rooms and for booking using any google API. In google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/domain), it is mentioned that:

> The Calendar API does not offer a way to create resource calendars. To do this, you need to use the Directory API's [Calendar Resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/resources.calendars) object.

But the link mentioned refers to the creating calendar resource, not resource calendar!

Answer (score 0):

Think of a resource room more like a user.

> You can book resources and rooms by adding them to events as attendees, using their email address. When they receive the invitation, they automatically accept or decline the event based on the availability and access right of the inviting user.

Its not really a calendar. By adding the resource as an attendee for an event you are booking that room.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I got that idea from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSD0Twg9ngk) that has created several resource calendars per each calendar resource.

Comment: its an interesting use case I may have to test this myself.

Comment: And how to set available time slots for that resource for booking? I am not meaning "Appointment slot" as it doesn't have any API.

Comment: I don't know why that google documentation is confusing — that is talking about creating 
  resource calendar, but the link mentioned addresses to create calendar resources!

Comment: IMO you are being to kind the  google documentation is confusing isn't confusing its completely lacking in a lot of places.    I have added it to my list of things to test but its a long list and I am in the middle of a few other projects for clients right now.   Let me know what you work out.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to develop a mechanism to send our meeting rooms to google calendar as resources, so that users could book them from the calendar side beside our application portal as well. The front barriers are "how to set a time slot for the resources to availability and unavailability?" and "how to create a new resource calendar by any API?" which is related to the question I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you don't need to create a resource calendar for your calendar resource as every calendar resource actually has its own calendar.
Therefore, to achieve that manually you can go to your google calendar, on the left side click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button next to the <kbd>Other calendars</kbd> and then select `Browse Calendars`, and finally click on a resource, In this way you can see the respective calendar which is unified for a resource.

Additionally, you can use the following URL by filling in your resource id which actually is its `resourceEmail`. To get that you can use the google admin API to get the list of resources.

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src={resourceEmail}&mode=WEEK&wkst=1&showCalendars=0
```